# Convert DataGridView to Datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have to convert a datagridview into a datatable, to make use of the code below, but I have some problems, the first and last row of datagridview are not inserted in the datatable and the hours field, contains this type of value 08:54, when it is inserted in the datatable the value becomes 08:00, how do I solve this?

**C# Code:**

```
DataTable dtemp = new DataTable();
dtemp.Clear();
dtemp.Columns.Add("Giorno");
dtemp.Columns.Add("DataINS");
dtemp.Columns.Add("Ore");
for (int row = 0; row < dataGridViewPrincipale.Rows.Count; row++)
{
   DataRow riga = dtemp.NewRow();
   riga["Giorno"] = dataGridViewPrincipale.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
   riga["DataINS"] = dataGridViewPrincipale.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   riga["Ore"] = dataGridViewPrincipale.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
   dtemp.Rows.Add(riga);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me whether it works or not?

Comment: @KamalaHB with your solution it does not work, it tells me: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @riki, how you insert data in the `DataGridView` in the first place?

Comment: There must be something else going on. The posted code works as expected. Using the posted code, it is not missing any rows and is posting “8:54” as expected… are you getting any errors? If the grids `DataSource` property has NOT been set, then, `dtemp = dataGridViewPrincipale.DataSource as DataTable;` will fail and throw a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

I am casting datagridView's datasource as DataTable and putting into datatable.

```
DataTable dtemp = new DataTable();
dtemp = dataGridViewPrincipale.DataSource as DataTable;
```

Comment: with your solution it does not work, it tells me: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Data is present in datagridView?

Comment: Just for my clarification. Did you replace your code with my code? Because when data is present in your datagridview, if you want to convert it to datatable, then you just have to initialize datatable like the way i did and put the datasource of datagridview to the the datatable by casting it.

Comment: @KamalaHB, looks like OP haven't used ``DataTable` as `DataSource`. Possibly data were inserted manually to the cells.